# Data from database to js charts

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel, highcharts

I have a javascript chart built with "highcharts" and I would display data from database in the chart.
I need to display data for each day of the week. I'm using laravel so I can use Carbon, but I don't know how.

Here is my view:

```
<div id="container"></div>
      <script>
     $(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Actions statistics'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07'] // days of the week
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Actions'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Submitted actions',
            data: [monday rows, tuesday rows, wednesday rows, thursday rows, friday rows, saturday rows, sunday rows] 
// data can be retrieved from database where them are stored with "created at" column.
// Something like Actionshistory::where('created_at', first day of the week)?

        }
    ]
    });
});     
      </script>
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks

**Solved**

I solved using this in the javascript:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Actions submitted',
    data: [<?php echo Actionshistory::whereRaw('WEEKDAY(created_at) = 0')->count() ?>,and so go on]
}
```

0=Monday, 1=Tuesday,ecc...
Thanks to all.

Comment: I found this little tutorial which might be helpful for you... http://i-am-sean.co.za/highcharts-laravel-4/

Comment: Refer this documentation: `http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database`

Comment: Thanks.I read te tutorial. But my problem is retrieving the data for each day of the week from the database.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your report is supposed to look, but it sounds like you'd need to use `DAYOFWEEK()` but not sure if it should be a select or grouped by that, I'm assuming select. `Actionshistory::select(DB::raw('DAYOFWEEK(created_at)'), 'some_other_column')->get();`

Comment: @user3158900 thank you! I solved using this `<?php echo Actionshistory::whereRaw('WEEKDAY(created_at) = 0')->count() ?>` 0=Monday,1=tuesday,ecc...

Comment: Nice!  Glad it worked out for you!